# Ответ ajax - разбор верстки

Tags: jquery, html

Добрый день!
В ф-ию $.ajax() приходит ответ от сервера в виде верстки. Ответ может быть 2х типов: в разных обёртках(т.е. разные id у дивов, допустим *id1* и *id2*).
Вопрос: можно ли как-то использовать селекторы jquery **перед** тем, как вставлять вёрстку в dom, что бы покопаться в ответе? Т.е. нужно просто определить, пришел ответ в первой обёртке, или второй. Спасибо!

**Дополнено**:
Я таким образом пытаюсь определить, какой тип ответа сервера. Привожу пример:
ответ может быть обёрнут в id=A и в id=B. Если данные пришли в обёртке А, то выполняю обновление информации на странице на основе ответа(удалил предыдущие - закинул новые), а если ответ в обёртке В, то провожу хитрые манипуляции полностью с страницей.
Более подробно расписать не могу, простите - производственная тайна ;) Вариант с отдачей сервером данных в json не подходит, как ни жаль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если данные возвращаются ввиде `html`, то к ним можно применить jQuery, но для этого, если верить [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/),  в `dataType` надо указать `html`:

```
...
$.ajax({
...
dataType: html,
...
success: function (result){
    if($(result).attr("id")==="id1")
    {
    //сделать одно
    }
    if($(result).attr("id")==="id2")
    {
    //сделать другое
    }
    else
    {
    //совсем плохой день=(
    }
});
```

---

Update:
**Исправил код**

Comment: Сейчас через атрибут попробуй залезть, а тип данных у меня и без того указан...

Comment: Браво! Как ни странно, но такие конструкции с атрибутами работают! Никогда бы не подумал... Большое спасибо, плюс вам :)

Comment: я уж хотел добавить ``$(result).attr("id")...``, но
jQuery не перестаёт приятно удивлять=)

Comment: Ну я и делал $(result).attr('id') и еще $(result).hasClass('someClass'). Просто result.attr() ругается на отсутствие метода.

Answer (score 0):

Было бы не плохо если напишите, что вы собираетесь сделать узнав с каким id пришел ответ?

Извените я не очень понял конечно но вы можете узнать class с помощью jquery задав этим div один и тот же id а потом узнать class этого id

```
var className = $('.мойид').attr('class');
```

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Что бы воспользоваться Вашей конструкцией, нужно закинуть ответ в dom, чего делать нельзя - я это указал в вопросе, и даже выделил.

Answer (score 0):

А find() пробовали: var idA = data.find('#a');

**upd** так он возвращает пустой массив, но если помещать результат в скрытый див и потом в нем искать элемент, то находит

Comment: Конечно пробовал, виснет скрипт и в консоли пишет весь ответ(верстка) + has no method 'find'.  
Пробовал var html = $(data).find('#a'); но выдаёт null

Comment: Обязательное условие - нужно узнать айдишник ответа **перед** добавлением кода в dom, я это указал в вопросе. Если ничего не придумаем - придётся так и делать, но это очень не хорошо в моей ситуации.